# Data reader give object reference not set to an instance of an object when data is extracted from it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am working on a new project I have to read data from one table and fetch multiple records from another table and save them in the same object. The problem is when I read multiple rows in the reader for my second query it works fine but when I assign them to the respective object variable it gives object reference error.

Here is my code. The first instance of reader returns only one data row but the second one returns multiple rows. What I have done until now I closed off one reader before opening the other one to check if it is a threading issue but now use.

```
        public AdjustmentRequest GetAdjustmentRequestData(AdjustmentRequest Request)
    {
        AdjustmentRequest RequestData = new AdjustmentRequest();
        using (OleDbConnection DbConnnection = new OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            DbConnnection.Open();

            //return list of all the Adjustment Categories
            string query = "select * from AdjustmentRequests where RequestID ='" + Request.RequestID + "' and [DistributorCode] = '" + Request.DistributorCode + "' and [BranchCode] ='" + Request.BranchCode + "'";

            OleDbCommand objOleDBcommand = new OleDbCommand(query, DbConnnection);
            OleDbDataReader ojbOleDBReader = objOleDBcommand.ExecuteReader();
            if (ojbOleDBReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (ojbOleDBReader.Read() == true)
                {
                    RequestData.RequestID = ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    RequestData.RequestStatus = ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    RequestData.InvoiceNumber = ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    RequestData.DistributorCode = ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    RequestData.BranchCode = ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(4).ToString();                        
                    RequestData.Comments = ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    RequestData.AdjustmentCategory = ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    RequestData.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(ojbOleDBReader.GetValue(7));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RequestData = null;
            }
            if (DbConnnection != null)
            {
                ojbOleDBReader.Close();                    
            }


            string query1 = "select * from AdjustmentRequestDetails where RequestID ='" + Request.RequestID + "'";

            OleDbCommand objOleDBcommandDetail = new OleDbCommand(query1, DbConnnection);
            OleDbDataReader ojbOleDBReaderDetail = objOleDBcommandDetail.ExecuteReader();


            if (RequestData != null)
            {
                if (ojbOleDBReaderDetail.HasRows)
                {
                    while (ojbOleDBReaderDetail.Read() == true)
                    {
                        if (ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString() == "Frait")
                        {
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.RequestID = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(0).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.AdjustmentCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.AdjustmentCategory = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.BrandCostCenter = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(3).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.AmountRequested = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(4).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.AmountApproved = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(5).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.Status = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(6).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.Assignee = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(7).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.UpdatedDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(8).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.UpdatedBy = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(9).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.ApproveRejectDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(10).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailFreight.RejectionCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(11).ToString();
                        }
                        if (ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString() == "Handling")
                        {
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.RequestID = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(0).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.AdjustmentCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.AdjustmentCategory = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.BrandCostCenter = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(3).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.AmountRequested = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(4).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.AmountApproved = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(5).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.Status = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(6).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.Assignee = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(7).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.UpdatedDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(8).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.UpdatedBy = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(9).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.ApproveRejectDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(10).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailHandling.RejectionCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(11).ToString();
                        }
                        if (ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString() == "Shipping Charges")
                        {
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.RequestID = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(0).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.AdjustmentCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.AdjustmentCategory = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.BrandCostCenter = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(3).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.AmountRequested = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(4).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.AmountApproved = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(5).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.Status = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(6).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.Assignee = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(7).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.UpdatedDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(8).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.UpdatedBy = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(9).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.ApproveRejectDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(10).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailShippingCharges.RejectionCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(11).ToString();
                        }
                        if (ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString() == "Other")
                        {
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.RequestID = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(0).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.AdjustmentCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(1).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.AdjustmentCategory = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(2).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.BrandCostCenter = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(3).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.AmountRequested = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(4).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.AmountApproved = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(5).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.Status = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(6).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.Assignee = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(7).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.UpdatedDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(8).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.UpdatedBy = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(9).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.ApproveRejectDate = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(10).ToString();
                            RequestData.RequestDetailOther.RejectionCode = ojbOleDBReaderDetail.GetValue(11).ToString();
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
            if (DbConnnection != null)
            {
                ojbOleDBReaderDetail.Close();
                DbConnnection.Close();
            }

        }

        return RequestData;
    }
```

Comment: is `RequestData.RequestDetailFreight` not `NULL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestion of @Shyju I initilized the inner objects in the main objects constructor and it worked like a charm. Thank you @Shyju.

Here is what i did.
I was unable to read data in RequestData.RequestDetailFreight because the main object RequestData was initilized but the inner objects were not. so i had to do this in the AdjustmentRequest class RequestData is an object of this class.

```
    public AdjustmentRequest()
    {
        RequestDetailFreight = new AdjustmentRequestDetailFreight();
        RequestDetailShippingCharges = new AdjustmentRequestDetailShippingCharges();
        RequestDetailHandling = new AdjustmentRequestDetailHandling();
        RequestDetailOther = new AdjustmentRequestDetailOther();
        RequestDetailNew = new List<AdjustmentRequestDetailNew>();
    }
```